# What is the proper way to use ReSharper's Projects to Ignore code inspection setting?

Tags: resharper, resharper-2018

We have a Visual Studio solution that is using third-party projects for code. These are essentially projects on GitHub that developers could use for their own implementations of a web application.

Within TeamCity we're getting code inspection warnings and errors for these projects that we don't intend on fixing, since we have little ability to shape the styling that they have.

Within ReSharper 2018.2.3 there's the ability within **Code Inspection** > **Settings** to specify **Projects to Ignore**, however [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2018.2/Reference__Options__Code_Inspection__Settings.html) and web in general are lacking in examples, and questions here cover ReSharper before it had this functionality.

If I wanted to exclude projects matching the pattern of Xxx.Yyy.*.csproj, what would be the proper way to add to the **Projects to Ignore**?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation seems to be updated

> To add projects to the ignore list, either use project file names, e.g.  ProjectOne.csproj or file masks, e.g.  Project*.csproj to match  ProjectOne.csproj,  ProjectTwo.csproj, etc.
>
> Note that the projects listed here will not be ignored when you run code inspection from the command line.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2018.2/Reference__Options__Code_Inspection__Settings.html#8244ec57

The problem is with the last sentence - it would not be respected when you run code inspection from command line, so it would be probably ignored in the CI. However, according to the documentation, you should be able to exclude projects using the "Elements to skip" [section](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Configuring_Warnings.html#exclude_items).